# How to Auto Resize textarea in Materializecss in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I am using Materializecss with React.js. The [document](https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html) only gives jQuery implementation of auto-resizing of textarea instead of pure Javascript.

```js
 $('#textarea1').val('New Text');
  M.textareaAutoResize($('#textarea1'));
```

How can I reach it with pure Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

To use Materialize with React, you should use `npm install materialize-css@next npm install react-materialize` where you can use components

Textareas allow larger expandable user input. The border should light up simply and clearly indicating which field the user is currently editing. Textareas will auto resize to the text inside.
Source:

```
<Row>
  <Textarea
    id="Textarea-12"
    l={12}
    m={12}
    s={12}
    xl={12}
  />
</Row>
```

[Learn more about React Materilize](https://react-materialize.github.io/react-materialize/?path=/story/components-textarea--textarea)

Comment: The question was about height adjustment, Materialize wants you to trigger an auto-resize whenever you programmatically modify the text inside the textbox, but in the documentation, they don't say how to do it in vanilla JS, only jQuery.